# Number of tests passed on TeamCity: -48

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I use TeamCity 9.x.

I recently noticed the following peculiar error message:

[image]

Is this a known bug? Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: more details, please; what build runner are you using (maven / ant / grunt / node scripts etc.)? what is your test runner? how does your build configuration look? what's in the build step used for testing? what test coverage tool are you using?

Comment: the more i think about it, the more it looks like a bug in the coverage-tool/test-runner reporter. it's just a guess, though